# How to Drop a Row in R Based on the First Column

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a `data.frame` setup like this:

```
df <- data.frame(units = c(1.5, -1, 1.4),
              what =  c('Num1', 'Num2', 'Num3'))
```

Which gives me something like this:

```
  units         what
1 1.500000     Num1
2 -1000000      Num2
3  1.400000      Num3
```

I want to  able to remove the entire row if the number in the first column is -1. So Ideally loop through the whole dataframe and remove the rows that have -1 in the unit column. I've been trying things like this:

```
if(CONDITION TO REMOVE) {
    print("deleting function...")
    df <- df[-c(df[,'Num2']),]
  }
```

But it deletes everything in the rest of the df. I only want to delete that one row (and the entire row).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does `df[-which(df$units==-1),]` work for you?

Comment: No, I'm getting this error `Warning: Error in $: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable`

Comment: It works for me for the dummy dataset you gave. Are you using it on an object `df` of type `data.frame`?

Comment: I'm using it on type data.frame

Answer (score 1):

```
newdf <- df[-which(df[,1] ==-1),]
```

newdf is df without the rows containing -1 in the first column.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dplyr` to better suit your needs:

```
df.new <- df %>% filter(units != -1)
```

Or you can do this using base R

```
df.new <- df[df$units != -1, ]
```